# Calculate the mean from a specific date

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have two dataframes.

I would like to make the average of sp variable for the previous 5 days defined by a specific date from a second dataframe.

For example, the mean from the day 1997.05.05 (that would be between the day 1997.05.05 and 1997.05.01) and the average between 1997.05.27 and 1997.05.31 calculate the days that have values (in this case 3).

Here are the variables:

```
sp < - c(7,9,9,4,2,5,2,9,NA,14,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,14,25,NA,11,10,12,NA,9,NA,6,8,6,1,NA,7,NA)

Date <- c("1997-05-01","1997-05-02","1997-05-03","1997-05-04","1997-05-05",
              "1997-05-06","1997-05-07","1997-05-08","1997-05-09","1997-05-10",
              "1997-05-11","1997-05-12","1997-05-13","1997-05-14","1997-05-15",
              "1997-05-16","1997-05-17","1997-05-18","1997-05-19","1997-05-20",
              "1997-05-21","1997-05-22","1997-05-23","1997-05-24","1997-05-25",
              "1997-05-26","1997-05-27","1997-05-28","1997-05-29","1997-05-30",
              "1997-05-31")

data1 <- data.frame(sp, Date)

DateX <- c("1997-05-05","1997-05-15","1997-05-31")

data2 <- data.frame(DateX)
```

how to do that best? Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my expected result (in the second dataframe, data2):

```
 1. DateX  spMean 
 2. 1997-05-05 6.2
 3. 1997-05-15 NA
 4. 1997-05-31 4.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a few type changes to your initial code. Give the below a shot...I use `lapply` to run a quick function against the `data1` object using the dates in your second object.

```
sp <- c(7,9,9,4,2,5,2,9,NA,14,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,14,25,NA,11,10,12,NA,9,NA,6,8,6,1,NA,7,NA)

Date <- as.Date(c("1997-05-01","1997-05-02","1997-05-03","1997-05-04","1997-05-05",
          "1997-05-06","1997-05-07","1997-05-08","1997-05-09","1997-05-10",
          "1997-05-11","1997-05-12","1997-05-13","1997-05-14","1997-05-15",
          "1997-05-16","1997-05-17","1997-05-18","1997-05-19","1997-05-20",
          "1997-05-21","1997-05-22","1997-05-23","1997-05-24","1997-05-25",
          "1997-05-26","1997-05-27","1997-05-28","1997-05-29","1997-05-30",
          "1997-05-31"))

data1 <- data.frame(sp, Date)

DateX <- as.Date(c("1997-05-05","1997-05-15","1997-05-31"))

data2 <- data.frame(DateX)

#Add column for mean, NA values return NA
data2$spMean_na <- lapply(DateX, 
               function(m) mean(data1$sp[data1$Date >= m - 5 & data1$Date <= m]))

#Add column for mean, remove NA values
data2$spMean_na_omit <- lapply(DateX, 
                          function(m) mean(data1$sp[data1$Date >= m - 5 & data1$Date <= m], 
                                           na.rm = TRUE))

> data2
       DateX spMean_na spMean_na_omit
1 1997-05-05       6.2            6.2
2 1997-05-15        NA             14
3 1997-05-31        NA            5.5
```

I think you might need to change your expected result. Row 29 has an `NA` for the `sp` value and is within 5 days of `1997-05-31`. So it should return an `NA` per your requirements as I understand them.

Comment: Hi, Nick. thank you so much. I think I did not write correctly... I would also like it to do the average when only 2, 3 or 4 lines within the dates were values. Do you have any idea how you could include this in the function?

Comment: @Gustavo, I made a change per your request. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, incredible! Thank you very much!!